# If any "antenna" can be impedance matched to the source, can any piece of metal be tuned to perform the same as a physically tuned antenna?

Tags: power, noise, antenna, impedance

I have heard online its better to get an antenna physically tuned than a matching network, but I don't understand exactly why. If the matching network would stop reflections and increase power incident, then if the same power is outputting, why is there even such thing as these large antennas, other than their directivity properties?

Comment: "I have heard online": Where. Context matters. That statement is not generally correct. In fact, it's pretty much nonsense but for a few special cases.

Comment: *If the matching network would stop reflections and increase power incident,* However, this is also not sensical: how would a matching network increase the power incident to the antenna? There's a causal link missing somewhere. So, where is the assumption that a matching network could increase power coming from? Again, cite your sources!

Comment: "Yes." Amateur radio operators can use almost anything to make an antenna.  http://www.vk2zay.net/article/158  https://www.dk9jc.de/blog/equipment/171-mag-loop-magnetic-loop-diy-with-trashed-26-inch-bicycle-rim

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi, my logic here was knowing that a matching network reduces reflections due to impedance mismatch, so if the power isnt reflected, it would have to go somewhear, hence the load? Is this logic wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons: efficiency, and bandwidth.

First, every matching network has some inefficiency, because it's made out of real components like inductors, capacitors, and transmission line. Mostly the loss is ohmic heating and dielectric loss (usually ohmic heating, unless the frequency is very high). A mismatched antenna is only radiating a small portion of the power fed to it, and reflecting the rest; the matching network's job is to re-reflect that power right back to the antenna. As the mismatch gets greater and the reflected power gets higher, the reactive currents involved also get higher, and the losses increase.

To some extent you can mitigate the efficiency problem by using lower-loss (i.e. bigger and more expensive) components in the matching network, but that isn't free any more than building a bigger antenna is.

The second reason is bandwidth: any matching network will only present a good match for a given antenna over a limited frequency range, and it's a general rule that the smaller you make the antenna, the narrower that useful bandwidth becomes. This is a little bit complicated, but matching networks are closely related to filters. If you start with that explanation of "the matching network takes the power the antenna reflects and re-reflects it", that's a resonant system, and its ideal Q goes up as the antenna SWR goes up (because the antenna is drawing a smaller fraction of the power out of it on each cycle).

Eventually you reach the point where, even for just a single center frequency, the useful bandwidth becomes smaller than the bandwidth of the signal that you want to transmit, and the whole system becomes entirely unworkable; the only solution is to reduce Q by deliberately adding loss, making the system even less efficient.

There are lots of applications that use "smaller than ideal" antennas and take a small efficiency hit for it. That's perfectly fine. But there's a limit; we can't just use 1mm antennas for everything.

Answer (score 13):

An antenna that is "the optimum length" for the operating frequency (i.e. "tuned"), will present an electrical resistance to a transmitter circuit that comprises 2 elements (a) the [radiation resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_resistance#:%7E:text=As%20can%20be%20seen%20in,%2C%20with%20sub%2Dresonant%20loops%20) and (b) the loss resistance (producing wasted heat).

\$\boxed{\text{ Example }}\$ a lossless antenna presenting 40 Ω radiation resistance and driven with (say) 1 volt RMS (at the right frequency), will deliver 25 mW into free-space.

<sub>Losses in a non-ideal antenna will add to the radiation resistance (maybe couple of ohm). Those losses can be regarded as negligible for the above example but not when the antenna is significantly shortened.</sub>

Note that the current will be 25 mA RMS (for comparison below).

Now, if the antenna was shortened to be one-tenth of the "optimum length" then, the radiation resistance reduces to a fraction of an ohm (disproportionate with the length reduction) and, radiation resistance becomes of the same order as the loss resistance: -

[image]

From wiki link above. Important part repeated below: -

> for linear antennas shorter than their fundamental resonant length
> (shorter than \$\frac{1}{2}\lambda\$ for a dipole antenna, \$\frac{1}{4}\lambda\$  for a monopole)
> the radiation resistance decreases with the square of their length

This means that you are immediately losing a sizable chunk of the 25 mW as heat and, instead of transmitting nearly 25 mW, you might only be transmitting 10 to 12 mW.

But, it's worse than this because you now need a matching network that converts the 50 Ω of your transmitter to something more like 0.5 Ω. That means even more loss. Think about trying to dump 11 mW into a 0.5 Ω resistor; the current will be around 150 mA RMS. So, unless you design your matching network with great care you might only get 5 to 10 mW out.

The above is for transmitting.

For receiving, the radiation resistance dropping to a fraction of an ohm means a tiny signal being received compared to using an optimally size antenna. Again, the reduction in signal is disproportionate with the length reduction.

Answer (score 4):

Matching only ensures that a given antenna can actually achieve its potential performance. But it doesn't change the properties of the antenna itself.

An electrically short antenna is still a lousy antenna. If you match it perfectly, you can get the entirety of the lousy performance, if it's mismatched it will perform, well, worse than merely lousy.

A matching network isn't free either, and adds losses of its own - although usually it's designed to keep those losses small relative to the radiated power. But that's not always possible. Matching to an antenna with very low radiation resistance is hard - the matching network will tend to be as lossy as the antenna itself.

Comment: Matching can cause  AE aperature to increase (that's how "chip antennas" in your phone can be 5mm wide.)  An electrically-small antenna is lousy because it's made from real-world lossy materials, and matched by a network containing resistive wires and finite-ESR capacitors.  Those odd textbook statements start working right when using zero-ohm materials.